# Importing numpy fails

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, chaco

I originally installed the anaconda distribution of python and have been coding primarily in Spyder. Recently I tried to install the Chaco visualization library and had a lot of trouble getting it to work using pip install - so instead I installed the Unthought Tool Suite which comes with Chaco. This means I now have two python distributions, but I'm not using virtualenv.

I get this error when running any code in Spyder using numpy:

```
ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/snoran/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
@rpath/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib Referenced from: 
/Users/snoran/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so Reason: image not found
```

When importing bumpy throguh the IPython console, I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

I am using Mac OS X

Comment: Looks to me like you installed 64 bit Numpy on 32 bit Python.

Comment: sorry I pressed enter too soon! Although that may be it! How can I check whether that may be the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to find whether bumpy is 64 bit or 32 bit, but my python must be 32 bit because    python-32 -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))' returns 32 and python-64 -c ... gives command not found. And my machine is 64 bit. But why would the Enthought installer install a 32-bit python version on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: It's not a 32-bit python (see the pathname) and it would not install a 32-bit package on a 64-bit python.

Comment: Is there a prior error message? The scimath error message is likely secondary to a prior error traceback. One quick thing to try is to delete the directory ~/.canopy in case your preferences file was corrupted, which is one possible source of such a prior error.

Comment: No but I decided to remove Enthought and anaconda, reinstall anaconda and though I never got Chaco working, that's ok because I discovered how to get the functionality I wanted with Bokeh. Thanks anyway